# Adding New row from textbox to DataGridView in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I Have form 1 with 4 textboxes and 1 button, and I have form 2 which contains dataGridView, I want to add new row to the datagridview from the other form.

the problem is When I click on Add button it open the main form with empty datagridview and add the row alone there, what should I do to make the new row be added to the datagridview in original form with the rest of rows.

```
Main frm = new Main();
StockDBDataSet ds = new StockDBDataSet();
DataRow obj = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
obj[0] = textBox1.Text;
obj[1] = textBox2.Text;
obj[2] = textBox4.Text;
obj[3] = dateTimePicker1.Value;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(obj);
ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
frm.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
this.Hide();
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot add it to data grid view you should add it to table then data grid will be updated automatically, by the way you can do it just by coding.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM yourTable", con);
da.Fill(ds, "yourTable");
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
string strCon2 = "server=yourserver; database=yourdb; integrated security=true;";
 SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strCon2);
 cmd2.Connection = con2;
 cmd2.CommandText =
 "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'yourTable') DROP TABLE yourTable CREATE TABLE yourTable(_id int primary key not null, name nvarchar(max), newColumn nvarchar(max));";
 cmd2.Connection.Open();
 cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cmd2.Connection.Close();
 dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
 dataGridView.DataMember = "yourTable";
```

I declared con inside form class, use this it will work but if the datagrid is in another form you should set dataGridView. DataSource and DataMemeber in that form and also you need to declare SqlDataAdapter and Dataset in that form to fill DataGrid View.